# layerClass breaks auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, calayer

I made a custom view which has `CAGradientLayer` as a layer, and I added this view on the other view with bottom anchor. It was just very simple auto layout constraint with bottom, leading, trailing and height constraints. However the bottom constraint doesn't work and it is always at the top(y == 0).

```
class GradientView: UIView {
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { CAGradientLayer.self }
    private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer { layer as! CAGradientLayer }

    var colors: [UIColor] = [.clear, .white] { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    var locations: [NSNumber] = [0, 1] { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = colors.map { $0.cgColor }
        gradientLayer.locations = locations
    }
}
```

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let gradient = GradientView()
        gradient.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(gradient)
        gradient.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        gradient.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        gradient.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        gradient.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    }
}
```

The result is like below. The gradient view is at the top, not bottom of the view.

[image]

I tried almost everything I could imagine and finally removed the `layerClass` and added the `CAGradientLayer` as a sublayer, and the constraint started working.

Is there anything I missed to override `layerClass` or it is kind of a bug?

Comment: I don't know what you mean about the constraint not working; you have shown no details and no evidence. The second version of your code, though, is wrong; your gradient layer now has no size.

Comment: @matt Yes I omitted that part because it doesn't really related. gradientLayer.frame = layer.bounds in the layoutSubview. When you add `GradientBlurView` as a subview of other view and add constraint with bottom, height and leading, the bottom constraint won't work. Read carefully. I provide everything you need.

Comment: I don't think you do. I've been using a gradient layer as a view's layer class for years and it works perfectly. You have not shown me how to not make it work. Consider providing a [mcve]

Comment: Also everything you say in your first paragraph is nonsense. "bottom, leading and height constraints" do not sufficiently determine a view's size, and the top is y==0 not "x == 0" as you have it.

Comment: @matt updated. It seems like the autolayout somehow works with layer? I tested it in iOS 17.2/iPhone 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You* are the one breaking autolayout. Delete this line:

```
gradientLayer.frame = bounds
```

The gradient, and the GradientView, will then appear where you expect them.

Comment: Why is this a problem? I'm not really understand how layer works with autolayout. It works though.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `layer` really. It has to do with how autolayout works. It works _in layoutSubviews_. So anything you do _after_ `super.layoutSubviews` is effectively _contradicting_ (overriding) the result of autolayout. So you were changing the frame of the GradientView from what it would have been if it had been left up to autolayout.